# Django Forms redirect on processing of a step in Wizard

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm trying to check a step once the form has been processed. It has 4 radio buttons on it with various values, and when any option but the 4th is pressed, I want it to redirect straight to a static page outside the wizard. Currently, I'm struggling to see a method that allows me to do this outside of `done()` (Too late in the flow) and `render()` (is called before the form on the page is processed). Has anyone else got an implementation or the correct method in the Django forms wizard to allow for a redirect?

Something like `process_step()` would have been the perfect method but the cannot return a redirect inside it.

Docs i'm looking at

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/

Answer (score 1):

You can override `WizardView`'s function `render_next_step` like this:

inside your form wizard class in `views.py` add:

```
def render_next_step(self, form, **kwargs):
    if self.steps.current == 'your_step':
        data = form.cleaned_data
        if data['your_radio1'] or data['your_radio2'] or data['your_radio3']:
            return render_to_response('your_template.html')
    return super().render_next_step(form, **kwargs)
```